# why $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] doesn't work in Android Webview?

Tags: php, android

I have an android app which shows a `webview`. the php funcion `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` doesn't work in the android app, but if i visit the same webpage with the stock browser (like chrome) it works

is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: It doesn't work because there's **no** `HTTP_REFERER` value.

Comment: $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is a PHP construct?!?!??! Are you running PHP or JAVA in your Andriod app?

Comment: why there is no reference value? obviously i'm not talking about the homepage

Answer (score 1):

referer is a optional clientside (user browser) header. you cant relay on that header. usualy its set by the browser when clicking links within the same protocol. browser may set it if the user allows it or may not.  so just never relay on client headers.

**solution:**
if you want to make sure the user comes from a special part of your page or view just append a parameter to the url and read it. like http://xy/newpage.php?ref=oldpage_id

if you want to call a page with headers from webview you can set them manualy:

```
String url = "http://target.xy/";

Map<String, String> Headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
Hearders.put("Referer", "http://target.xy/referer");

WebView wv;
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
```

Comment: that's not a solution because i need to store the referer in a cookie. if referer is an optional clientside header, there must be a way to add this function to the webview

Comment: in this way i must know the url and put it as a header. i don't know the referer, that's why i'm getting it by php

Comment: then your question doesnt make sense at all. as said referer is a optional clientside header just for links within pages you can set it if you have controll over the client. if you dont have crontoll ask the creator of the client either add a referer or a parameter to the url.

Comment: we're talking about a webview in my android app, so i'm the creator of the client. that's what i'm asking since the beginning

Comment: yes then you have controll of the headers and can set them as i said Hearders.put("Referer", "http://target.xy/referer"); and your php backend can read the referer header you gave you said you dont know the referer so why u dont know the referer if its your client